# Is it possible to change the database type of an enum in gorm (using postgres)?

Tags: database, postgresql, go, database-migration, go-gorm

I wonder if its possible to change the datatype of an enum in gorm when it has the same underlying type?

So say this is my current model

type A

```
type typeA int32

const (
    field1         typeA = 0
    field2         typeA = 1
    field3         typeA = 2
)
```

```
type typeB int32

const (
    field1         typeB = 0
    field2         typeB = 1
    field3         typeB = 2
)
```

And I have my gorm model like this

```
type MyModel struct {
    gorm.Model

    SomeField        typeA
}
```

I wonder if I could easily change my DB model to this (change in type, but same underlying type)
Or if this will cause some migration issues?

```
type MyModel struct {
    gorm.Model

    SomeField        typeB
}
```